# Error Message: "Property App\Aurora\Domain\Movement\Entity\Deposit::$type does not exist"

Tags: php, symfony, docker, caching, doctrine-orm

I have a Symfony 4 project deployed in a docker container. When I changed the $type property of Entity and from doctrine mapping yaml file to $typeOperation and tried to update database running the command `php bin\console doctrine:schema:update --force` I got the following error:

> Property App\Aurora\Domain\Movement\Entity\Deposit::$type does not exist

Tried as posted in other similar posts the next following commands:

> `php bin\console doctrine:cache:clear-result --env=prod`
>
> `php bin\console doctrine:cache:clear-query --env=prod`
>
> `php bin\console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata --env=prod`

Also tried:

> `php bin\console cache:pool:prune --env=prod`

After those always getting same error with `php bin\console doctrine:schema:update --force` or `php bin\console cache:clear env=prod`

Don't know what to try more. Thx.

I can't get docker container running because of that error, so running commands in local project dir.

This is the actual class:

```
namespace App\Aurora\Domain\Movement\Entity;


use App\Aurora\Domain\Movement\ValueObject\Concept;

class Deposit implements TypeOperation
{

/**
 * @var integer
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @var string
 */
protected $typeOperation;

/**
 * @var Concept
 */
protected $concept;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->typeOperation = get_class($this);
}

/**
 * @return int
 */
public function getId(): int
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getTypeOperation(): string
{
    return $this->typeOperation;
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getConcept(): string
{
    return $this->concept;
}

/**
 * @param Concept $concept
 */
public function setConcept(Concept $concept): void
{
    $this->concept = $concept;
}
```

}

This is the doctrine mapping:

```
App\Aurora\Domain\Movement\Entity\Deposit:
    type: entity
    table: deposits
    repositoryClass: App\Aurora\Infrastructure\Movement\DepositRepository
    id:
        type: integer
        generator: { strategy: AUTO }
    fields:
        typeOperation:
            type: string
            nullable: false
    OneToOne:
        concept:
            targetEntity: App\Aurora\Domain\Movement\ValueObject\Concept
            cascade: [ 'persist', 'remove' ]
            fetch: EAGER
```

Comment: Can you please provide the source code of the mentioned class App\Aurora\Domain\Movement\Entity\Deposit?

Comment: @W0rma Ok, done.

Comment: The content of the doctrine yaml mapping file would be interesting, too

Comment: @w0rma Sorry, I ve posted it. Thx for your time.